# Terminar programa com enter/ EOF

Tags: c, loop, while, comparação, null

Preciso que o código termine após um enter vazio, sem nenhuma entrada ou o 'EOF', mas não sei como aplicá-lo e não entendi muito bem os exemplos que vi. O programa está quase completo, pede para ficar num ciclo de ler 2 numeros e mostrar a soma deles, mas justamente por causa do 'enter vazio' ele entra em "Time limit exceeded".
O código

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main() {
    int n1, n2, sum;
    
    do{
        scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
        sum = n1 + n2;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }while((scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2) != '\n'));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Você citou que você obteve um "Time Limit Exceeded". Portanto, esse código é uma resposta para um problema de programação no estilo URI Online Judge/HackerRank/etc., correto?

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo do tipó:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n1=0, n2=0, sum;
    do{
        sum = n1 + n2;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    } while((scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2) != EOF));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    sum = n1 + n2;
    printf("%d\n", sum);
}while((scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2) != '\n'));
```

Você tem um livro sobre C? um manual?

Leu algo sobre `scanf()`? Pode tentar aqui [em Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-scanf-l-wscanf-wscanf-l?view=vs-2019)

Lá diz

```
int scanf(
   const char *format [,
   argument]...
);
```

`scanf()` retorna um `int` com o total de valores lidos, ou EOF --- (-1) --- e você devia usar SEMPRE. Ou melhor: deve usar sempre a menos que não seja importante saber se leu algo.

Em seu programa usou só uma vez e de modo estranho: você está tentando ler dois valores:

```
scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2)
```

então `scanf()` vai retornar o que? -1 para EOF, zero, 1 ou 2. E você comparara com o que? `'\n'` que por acaso vale 10.
Assim não é estranho que seu programa fique nesse loop por toda a eternidade.

E porque não testou na primeira leitura se leu dois valores? Acha que vai ficar tudo bem se o cara digitar um só? ou nenhum? Não vai.

E notou no loop não vai nunca somar as séries pares?

Seu programa lê o primeiro par e soma. Aí lê o segundo par **e o terceiro** antes de somar. Lá se vai o segundo. E aí **lê o quarto e o quinto** antes de somar: lá se vai o quarto par...

Isso se o cara digitar mesmo um par a cada vez...

Testou isso?

Comment: Note que, de acordo com a documentação: "If the input ends before the first conversion (if any) has completed, and without a matching failure having occurred, EOF shall be returned."